# Error while promoting Widget container in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I've created my own class in QT 5.4 with header and source file, then I've implemented there a video player. The problem is, that it's working fine when I'm placing it in the center of the main window or when I'm showing it in a separate window, but when I'm trying to create a Widget container in the main window and promote widget to it, it gives me some errors:

'videowindow' does not name a type

'widget' was not declared in this scope

expected type-specifier before 'videowindow'

So, here is the code:

videowindow.h - header of my implemented class

```
#ifndef VIDEOWINDOW_H
#define VIDEOWINDOW_H

#include "mainwindow.h"

class videoWindow
{
private:
    QMediaPlayer *player;
    QMediaPlaylist *playlist;
public:
    videoWindow();
    void video_enable();
    void widget();
};

#endif // VIDEOWINDOW_H
```

videowindow.cpp - source

```
#include "videowindow.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

videoWindow::videoWindow()
{
}

void videoWindow::video_enable()
{
player = new QMediaPlayer;

playlist = new QMediaPlaylist;
playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("D:\\фото\\video\\P1150277.MOV"));

QVideoWidget *videoWid = new QVideoWidget;
player->setVideoOutput(videoWid);

videoWid->show();
player->setPlaylist(playlist);
playlist->setCurrentIndex(1); // start from a first video in the playlist
player->play();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtMultimedia>
#include <QtMultimediaWidgets>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <string>
#include <QGraphicsVideoItem>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "videowindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "videowindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

InstantPlayer.pro - .pro file of the project

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-06-24T11:37:26
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = InstantPlayers
TEMPLATE = app

@
QT += multimedia
QT += multimediawidgets
@

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    videowindow.cpp \
    playerbase.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    videowindow.h \
    playerbase.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    playerbase.ui
```

Comment: The question is of course about C++ and whether you included  header / declared the class member of that type / etc. Your example shows nothing for video window being added to other widget class to start talk about. BTW the common convention is to name classes starting with capital letter. For video window that would be VideoWindow. I would call that VideoWidget as long as it uses widget base.

Comment: @AlexanderVX, no, right now i've added the "videowindow.h" to my mainwindow.h header, but that's not working. I really don't know how this thing works in qt and the problem is in the file that generates automatically.

Comment: Check the line number on the error message. If you copy-pasted the error message exactly from your IDE, my first guess is that this is a simple typing error. The error message says it does not know type `videowindow`(note the lower-case "w") but you have defined the class as `videoWindow` (with upper-case "W"). Verify the correct case at the line number of the error

Comment: @RobbieE Thanks for your reply, but that's not the whole problem. The problem is, that i was trying to mix classic UI writing via code with QT Designer and there was a conflict. Now i'm writing code only, because QT Designer connected to classic Qt isn't so good as i want. Thanks for help, though.

Comment: In that case, double-check the spelling you used in QtDesigner when you promoted your widget container to `videoWindow`. Also, make sure your `videoWindow` class inherits from `QWidget`

Comment: It would help a lot if you pasted the exact error messages (in their entirety) that your compiler generates, rather than just the pieces you think are important. Its often the case that things you think are irrelevant turn out to be vital clues to a problem when looked at through fresh eyes